# What data type use instead of 'ntext' data type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to write a trigger for one of my tables which has an `ntext datatype` field an as you know the trigger can't be written for `ntext datatype`.
Now I want to replace the `ntext` with `nvarchar` datatype. `The ntext` maximum length is 2,147,483,647 character whereas `nvarchar(max)`  is 4000 character.
what datatype can I use instead of `ntext` datatype. 
Or are there any ways to write trigger for when I have `ntext` datatype?
It's better to say my database is designed before with SQL 2000 and it is full of data.

Comment: For SQL Server **2000** (which is several years out of any official support by now) there is no alternative, unfortunately.

Comment: **SQL Server 2005** (which is also out of official Microsoft support by now) introduced a new datatype `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which can hold up to 2 GB and supports all regular string functions in T-SQL.

Comment: You can use an INSTEAD OF trigger with a text data type, so I'm assuming ntext will work as well.

Comment: By this :" It's better to say my database is designed before with SQL 2000 and it is full of data." did you mean that the db is running in a sql 2000 instance, or in 2000 level compatebility on a sql 2005 or 2008 db?

Comment: It's running in a sql 2000 instance.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck with sql server 2000, but you can possibly chain together a bunch of nvarchar(4000) variables. Its a hack, but it may be the only option you have. I would also do an assesment of your data, and see what the largest data you actually have in that column. A lot of times, columns are made in anticipation of a large data set, but in the end it doesn't have them.

Comment: No, this will not work.  Each such such column can contain up to 8000 bytes.  Two such columns could easily bust the maximum row size of 8060 bytes.  This would be "Timebomb design" at best.

Comment: @brock: Its not for saving, but for manipulating it in the trigger. The real solution is to do an assesment first whether ntext is actually required.

Comment: You cannot use `ntext` columns in the 'inserted' or 'deleted' tables.  Hence you can't use them in a trigger.  Thus, for any kind of nvarchar(4000) swap, you'd need to alter how the data was stored.  If you can get around this, show or link to how.

Answer (score 0):

in MSDN i see this :
*** Important ***
ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and Unicode character and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2 character set.

and it preferd nvarchar(MAX) , You can see details below :

nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ] 
Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

Comment: nvarchar(max) Variable width Unicode string. Maximum 536,870,912 characters